# Submit job via Postman and retrieve the response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman

I am not able to submit a job via [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) in my google data processing cluster. I want to submit a job via POST request, but the server told me that it's not able to receive POST messages.

Do you know what kind of problem could it be?

Can you provide me a simple example in order to understand if I am doing properly the things?

Answer (score 0):

If the server can't accept a POST request, then you can't force them to receive that request.

What does their documentation say with regards to this?